# Kinetic energy of quarks in a proton

Tags: particle-physics, inertial-frames, quarks, protons, strong-force

If we say that a proton has a kinetic energy of 50 GeV, can we say that each of the three quarks that compose it have roughly a **mean** energy of $\approx \frac{50}3=17$ GeV?

Comment: No. see what the main stream physics  model of a  proton  at the level of quarks is composed of here : https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/

Comment: @annav Then what can we say about the energy of each quark?

Comment: as with all quantum mechanical states, individual quark energies cannot be predicted, a main stream quantum mechanical theoretical model can give a prediction of the distribution of energies, and the **probability** of a specific quark having that energy.